# HTML buttons switch

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modbus

I have four buttons, each deciding which speed the fan in a hotel room should have. SO if the user clicks on one button other buttons should be in OFF mode. Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Now I have four buttons that users can turn on simultaneously, which does not make sense for my application.

```
$("#wentAOnOff").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'do',
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                actions:[
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1175", val: 1},
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1062", val: 1},
                ]
            },
            success: function(res) {
            },
            error : function() {
            }
        });
    });

    $("#went1OnOff").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'do',
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                actions:[
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1176", val: 1},
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1062", val: 1},
                ]
            },
            success: function(res) {
            },
            error : function() {
            }
        });
    });
    $("#went2OnOff").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'do',
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                actions:[
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1177", val: 1},
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1062", val: 1},
                ]
            },
            success: function(res) {
            },
            error : function() {
            }
        });
    });
    $("#went3OnOff").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'do',
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                actions:[
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1178", val: 1},
                    {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: "1062", val: 1},
                ]
            },
            success: function(res) {
            },
            error : function() {
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class and data attributes

```js
const $went = $(".went")// all 4 buttons by class
  .on("click", function() { // any of them
  const id1 = this.dataset.id1;
  const id2 = this.dataset.id2;
  $went.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
/*
  $.ajax({
    url:'do',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
      actions:[
        {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: id1, val: 1},
        {action: "set", what: "mbt", id: id2, val: 1},
      ]
    },
    success: function(res) { },
    error : function() { }
  });
*/  
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="went" data-id1="1175" data-id2="1062">Off</button>
<button class="went" data-id1="1176" data-id2="1062">Off</button>
<button class="went" data-id1="1177" data-id2="1062">Off</button>
<button class="went" data-id1="1178" data-id2="1062">Off</button>
```

Comment: I think you meant to use your cached `const $went = $(".went");`  but still, nearly exactly what I would have suggested

Comment: I borrowed your answer and used data attributes and added a button to turn all off :) I am a thief!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss of course - thanks (for pointing out I forgot I cached, not the stealing)

Answer (score 0):

it's not that clear to me what is the problem, turn off the 3 other buttons or the ajax calls? What doesn't make sense?

Anyway, you can iterate all the buttons on every `click` and switch off the ones that are not the button the user clicked on. You can use jQuery to get all the buttons and iterate them. Because you have the ID of the clicked element you can turn off all the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed much of this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72828887/125981 but added ability to turn all the fans off with one click; and toggled the text in CSS by using a data attribute not toggling of classes.

```js
const $went = $(".went"); // all 4 buttons by class
$went.on("click turnoff", function(event) { // any of them
  const id1 = this.dataset.id1;
  const id2 = this.dataset.id2;
  this.dataset.fan = this.dataset.fan === "off" ? "on" : "off";;
  if (event.type === "turnoff") {
    this.dataset.fan = "off";
  }

  let mydata = {
    actions: [{
        action: "set",
        what: "mbt",
        id: id1,
        val: 1
      },
      {
        action: "set",
        what: "mbt",
        id: id2,
        val: 1
      },
    ]
  };

  /*
    $.ajax({
      url:'do',
      type:'POST',
      data:mydata
      })
      .done(result){})
      .fail(xrf){});
  */
});
$('.all-off').on('click', function() {
  $went.trigger('turnoff');
});
```

```css
.went[data-fan="on"] {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}

.went[data-fan="on"]:after {
  content: 'On';
}

.went[data-fan="off"] {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.went[data-fan="off"]:after {
  content: 'Off';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="went" data-id1="1175" data-id2="1062" data-fan="off"></button>
<button class="went" data-id1="1176" data-id2="1062" data-fan="off"></button>
<button class="went" data-id1="1177" data-id2="1062" data-fan="off"></button>
<button class="went" data-id1="1178" data-id2="1062" data-fan="off"></button>
<button class="all-off">All Off</button>
```